# How do I import a project with modules to another project, and not lose my encapsulation?

Tags: java, module, java-9

I am trying to build a small weather client API that will fetch some weather from some website. In doing so, I would like to have a single entry point to my project (call it WeatherClient).

I have separated the project into different packages (for simplicity lets just say I have 2 packages, an "external" package, and an "internal" package).

I only want my WeatherClient in the external package, and have a public class in the internal package (`WeatherClientBuilderImpl` with `public builder()`).

What I am trying to achieve is to hide the WeatherClientBuilderImpl when importing the project. From what I have read on modules it seems like this is exactly one of their primary benefits, yet I have sadly been unable to find anything about how to achieve this

**I have tried a few things:**

1. I have tried creating 2 modules: internal, and external. I have tried to just import the internal .jar (whose pom includes the dependency for the module) - The main issue I face here is getting a ClassNotFound exception at runtime.
2. I have tried creating 1 module and only exporting the external package. This doesn't work (I'm guessing because "export" exports the module and not the packages). Here I end up being able to implement any of the classes, which defeats my purpose.

This is my current tree and more or less what I would have liked to have (I tried doing some stuff with modules by placing my WeatherClient in an "external" package and then creating 2 modules (one for external, one for internal).

```
.
|-- WeatherClient.java
|-- internal
|   |-- DarkKey.java
|   |-- DarkSkyClient.java
|   |-- InvalidParametersException.java
|   |-- WeatherBuilderImpl.java
|   `-- handlers
|       |-- JsonBodyHandler.java
|       `-- JsonBodyHandlerTwo.java
`-- model
    |-- DateTimeFormatException.java
    |-- DateValidator.java
    `-- WeatherRequest.java
```

To be clear, what I'm trying to achieve is to import this project into a separate project, in such a way that a client can only be created by using the WeatherClient class.

Comment: _I'm guessing because "export" exports the module and not the packages_. Nope `export` is used to export packages not modules.

Comment: Instead of doing this, you should probably just make the builder constructor, package private. Hiding the builder class in a module means you cannot use it outside your module, not even the `builder` method in your `WeatherClient` class, because nobody outside the module can `read` that package, unless you use compile time options to `open` the package to another module, but then this defeats the purpose of the encapsulation you were going for

Comment: Thanks for the feedback smac.. I started with that, but it meant that everything was in a single package. For this little project I could get away with that, but it feels wrong. Have a look at the structure for java.net.http (I'm sure there are tons of examples like this though). Here they explicitly export only the classes that they want to have used and then don't export everything internal. This is the idea that I am trying to achieve. Perhaps modules is just not the way though..

Comment: When you are using Java 9 modules, you have to create a `module-info.java` file containing the definitions. What has written into a pom file, is irrelevant.